# Why our children called as **ward** in the school?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

As i checked several email from my daughter school mail communication and i found a strange salute for my child.

> Your ward has successfully moved one more step ahead. You ward is now in Grade 2 section C

Why our children called as **ward** in the school ?

Please explain.

Comment: The only circumstances in which it would make sense to me, would be if it were addressed to the guardians of a child, who was a *ward of court*. Are you in the UK?

Comment: No，i am staying in Middle East

Comment: Even in India this is common. I don't know the reason why students are called "wards".

Comment: @AbhilashThomas In that case I would suggest it has something to do with the customs and law of the country in which you are resident. It would be an unusual way to communicate with a parent, or guardian in the UK. The normal thing would be to mention the child by name.

Comment: See also [School calls my daughter a ward](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/14421/school-calls-my-daughter-a-ward) on ELL.

Comment: They use "ward" to cover all the bases -- it includes the children with parents, guardians, under temporary custody for some reason, etc.  It avoids awkward wordings when simply saying "child" might be taken to mean your biological child and cause confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ward is a slightly old-fashioned term for something/someone that is under the stewardship of someone else. As you are the guardian of your child, they are the ward of their parent.

[Ward](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ward):

> a person or thing under guard, protection, or surveillance as a
>
> - minor subject to wardship,
> - a person who by reason of incapacity (as minority or mental illness) is under the protection of a court either directly or through a guardian appointed by the court —called also ward of court,
> - a person or body of persons under the
>   protection or tutelage of a government

[Wardship](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wardship):

> care and protection of a ward,
>
> the right to the custody of an infant heir of a feudal tenant and of the heir's property.
>
> the  state of being under a guardian

Comment: I remember from my youth that Dick Grayson, who was the street-clothes version of Robin, was the ward of Bruce Wayne, who was Batman.  That means that Bruce Wayne, who had the financial means to do so, took on the legal responsibility for Dick Grayson, who was a minor.

Comment: Coincidentally, on the 1960s TV show _Batman_, Dick Grayson (aka Robin) was played by an actor named Burt Ward.

Answer (score 3):

Not all childen are in the care of both parents: some, after remarriage, live with step-parents, and others, being orphaned, live with guardians, whether relatives or state-ordained. In the latter case *ward* is precisely the right term. The school authorities, who have to send out one communication to all 'parents', may think it insensitive to use *your child* universally and are probably unable or unwilling to discover the exact relationship in each case. *Your ward*, though slightly jarring, is not inaccurate.

Comment: Somehow it would be so much more human, if they just added the name of the child instead of doing this slightly awkward thing. I mean, if this is automatically generated and queries the correct grade and section it could surely query the name.

Comment: I would be disappointed in any teacher who didn't appear even to know my child's name.

Comment: @skymningen - Adding the child's name would require that each notice be individually "personalized", with care then being taken to assure that the correct notice was delivered to the correct parent.  That's an extra half-hour of work for a teacher in a classroom of 30 students.  Plus a lot of opportunity to screw up.

Comment: It does sound like the school is trying to cover all bases with an economy of words, but it would sound strange to use this wording in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks But it seems quite clear from the OP's question that the information is particular to a specific child. It states they are now in "grade 2 section C". So everything has to be individually addressed. And presumably the child has a name - so why not use it?

Comment: @HotLicks I expected the messages to be send out automatically, by querying a database.

Comment: @skymningen - In which case the database would likely not be aware of the specific legal status of the "parents".

Comment: @HotLicks No, but hopefully of the child's name.

Comment: This would be a good discussion for chat.